# !pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file .../texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map): fflush() failed (Invalid argument)

Tags: pdftex, texlive

I switched from MiKTeX to TeXLive, because I had installation trouble with MiKTeX on Windows 10. 
I'm trying to use pdflatex.exe to get a PDF document.
But now I got this error:

```
{d:/Program Files/TeXLive/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex
.map
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex.exe (file d:/Program Files/TeXLive/texlive/2019/texmf-v
ar/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map): fflush() failed (Invalid argument)
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

What can I do to solve this error? 
If you need more information, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've deleted all installlation and files of miktex. I opened the GUI via `tlshell -gui`? . `tlmgr -gui` said `Please use tlshell as a GUI for tlmgr`. Then in the menu point "Actions" of th GUI, I ran all 3 commands `Regenerate filename database`, `Regenerate formats` and `Regenerate fontmaps`. There were no updates left. Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: Yes, thanks. That's a good Idea. I will try this.

Comment: No idea if it is related but I would avoid spaces in the installation folder (`d:/Program Files`).

Comment: I tried the solution with a basic example and the result is the same. When the tex file is not correct another error is thrown, but when there is no error on the tex file itself it always throws this error.

Comment: Is texlive also on github, where I can also ask for help? I did not found it on github actually.

Comment: texlive has a mailing list. https://www.tug.org/texlive/

Comment: Works like a charm in the console...

Comment: Many thanks anyway for your help! I got it now working with TeXLive. It was an issue with PHP.